# Android Viewpager not working in SlidingDrawer?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slidingdrawer

I am trying to write a Viewpager which will have 3 slides, then after dragging from Top to Bottom another layout will appear. So, I am using **< SlidingDrawer >** to design the layout. But the issue is that whole layout is stuck. The viewpager is not moving at all and SlidingDrawer is also not working. Below I have mentioned my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.graphsexample;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   PagerContainer mContainer;
   LinearLayout viewLnr;
   ImageView viewImg;
   ViewPager pager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContainer = (PagerContainer) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);

    pager = mContainer.getViewPager();
    PagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
    // make this at least however many pages you can see
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
    //A little space between pages
    pager.setPageMargin(0);

    //If hardware acceleration is enabled, you should also remove
    // clipping on the pager for its children.
    pager.setClipChildren(false);
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);



    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Page - "+arg0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

//Nothing special about this adapter, just throwing up colored views for demo
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


        viewLnr = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

        viewLnr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33333333"));

        viewLnr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                viewImg = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

                    viewImg.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
                    viewImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    viewImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_bg);

                viewLnr.addView(viewImg);

        container.addView(viewLnr);

        return viewLnr;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lt"
    android:background="#33333333">

<SlidingDrawer 
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/pager_container"
    android:orientation="vertical">



            <com.example.graphsexample.PagerContainer
                    android:id="@+id/pager_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="#141349">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

             </com.example.graphsexample.PagerContainer>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:src="@drawable/love" />

</SlidingDrawer>


</FrameLayout >
```

[image]

The viewpager is not working whenever I am trying to declare it inside the SlidingDrawer, so please let me know some good solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: SlidingDrawer is deprecated since API17, this might be a reason.

Comment: So , what should be the min api version

Comment: So API16 should me the *max* api version, I guess. You shouldn't use SlidingDrawer.

Comment: So , what could be the alternative of SlidingDrawer to have Slide top to down animation in the app

Comment: A DrawerLayout probably.

Comment: yes DrawerLayout may be the alternative... i will try :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77800/discussion-between-mycode-and-m-vai).